GeoServer-OGC API Features - HTML Templates
I'm using GeoServer 2.25 in combination with the corresponding OGC API module.
The HTML view of the resource Features (/collections/{collectionId}/items) is controlled by the FreeMarker template named "getfeature-content.ftl"
The original template from GeoServer shows the feature name, but I need to show the feature title.
How can I access the title attribute?
